# Raspberry Pi Node.js GPIO control

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to command two motors connected with a l298n module from a RPI4. 
This is not working on node.js but the same script (sort of porting) in python works because motors run.

Python script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

in1 = 24
in2 = 23
en = 25

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(in1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
p=GPIO.PWM(en,1000)
p.start(25)

while(1):
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
```

JS script (maybe not interesting, launched with sudo):

```
var Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio;

const in1 = new Gpio(24, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
const in2 = new Gpio(23, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
const en = new Gpio(25, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});

in1.digitalWrite(0);
in2.digitalWrite(0);
en.pwmWrite(255);
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("finish"); }, 10000);
```

pigpiod -v gives me version 71

Where is the problem?
(PS: i started with https://www.npmjs.com/package/motor-l298n but when found that motors were not working i tried to go directly with pigpio). The project is in JS so python script is just to check that things works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this code works:

```
const Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio;

const in1 = new Gpio(24, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
const in2 = new Gpio(23, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
const en = new Gpio(25, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});

let dutyCycle = 0;
in1.digitalWrite(1);
    in2.digitalWrite(0);
setInterval(() => {
    en.pwmWrite(dutyCycle);

dutyCycle += 5;
if (dutyCycle > 255) {
    dutyCycle = 0;
}
}, 20);
```

so i'm gonna work on it

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error here is that both `in1.digitalWrite(0)` and `in2.digitalWrite(0)` have value of zero. The correct approach is that one should have the value of one: `in1.digitalWrite(1);` and `in2.digitalWrite(0);` OR `in1.digitalWrite(0);` and `in2.digitalWrite(1);`.